# How to calculate CPU service time on Windows and Linus OS for a running application

Tags: performance, cpu

How to calculate CPU service time on Windows and Linux OS for a running application? I believe this can be calculated as total time of running application multiply by % utilization of CPU but not sure. Also, What is CPU time and How CPU time is different than Service time?

Answer (score 1):

The windows task manager can show the cpu time (might have to enable it in the menu). In linux running the application with `time application` gives you the cpu time after the application has finished and I guess `top` or `htop` can show it for a running application.

The [cpu-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time) is the time used by the cpu(s) to process the instructions of the application. So for the given cpu-time the application used 100% of a CPU.

The usage of the CPU for a wall clock time intervall would be `(sum of all cpu times)/(wall clock time)` i.e if 10 application have 0.1s of cpu time in a frame of 1s the total utilization would be 100%.

CPU utilization for a given application would be `(cpu time)/(wall clock time)` for a single CPU or `(cpu time)/(#CPUs * wall clock time)` if it uses multiple CPUs.

So yes cpu-time would be `wall-clock-time*%CPU utilization`.

The diffence between CPU time and service time (called wall clock time above) is that service time is the time elapsed since the start of the application and the cpu time is the time it could/did actually use a CPU.